# JavaScript Filtro por Categoria

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, estou com um problema ao fazer um filtro de categoria, numa pagina de loja, existe varias categorias, os itens e o numero da categoria são retiradas do banco de dados MySQL.
Quando eu abro a pagina da loja, ele mostra todos os itens (até ai ok), quando eu clico em alguma categoria, ele filtra normalmente, porém quando clico em outra novamente, os itens somem, preciso dar *refresh* na pagina para que os itens apareçam novamente

A coleta dos itens:

```js
products: ko.observableArray([]),
    getProducts: function () {
        $.get("/api/webshop", 
        function (data) {
            if (!!data) {
                ctor.products(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

O filtro em categoria:

```js
Category: function (Category) {
    var products2 = ctor.products().filter(x => x.Category === parseInt(Category));
    ctor.products(products2);
},
```

O HTML:

```html
<div class="shop-wrapper">
    <aside class="player-cash"><span data-bind="text: 'Você possui ' + cashPoint() + ' coins'"></span></aside>
        <aside class="category-wrapper" >
        <header>Categorias</header>
            <div class="category" data-bind="click: Category.bind($root, '1')"><span> Itens 1 </span></div>
            <div class="category" data-bind="click: Category.bind($root, '2')"><span> Itens 2 </span></div>
            <div class="category" data-bind="click: Category.bind($root, '3')"><span> Itens 3 </span></div>
    </aside>
</div>
<div class="shop-wrapper">
    <div class="products-wrapper">
        <div class="product-row" data-bind="foreach: products">
            <div class="product">
                <div class="product-name" data-bind="text: Item.name"></div>
                <img data-bind="attr: { src: '../../img/mixmall/' + $data.ItemID     + '.png' }" height=84px width=84px />  
                <div class="product-price-wrapper">
                        <div class="money">$</div>
                        <div class="price" data-bind="text: Price"></div>
                </div>  
                <div class="product-actions">
                    <button data-bind="click: $root.onDetail">Detalhes</button>
                    <button data-bind="click: $root.buy"><span>Comprar</span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Parece que ele esta filtrando em cima do que já foi filtrado, já pesquisei e não encontrei como arrumar isso...
Conseguem me ajudar?

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: parecem estar faltando scripts para entender seu código. não sei como é criada a classe ctor e o que fazem as suas funções

Comment: Que informações você precisa? E de que forma posso passar?

Comment: precisa mostrar a classe ctor. acredito que seja de alguma api que você está usando. vem dessa api/webshop? pegou no github?

Comment: Não, é de um site que um colega fez pra mim, porém to fazendo algumas alterações e correções.

Comment: O JS da pagina WEB segue dessa forma: http://dontpad.com/webshopjs